# How can I delete id's if not in array (FMDB sqlite Swift iOS)?

Tags: ios, swift, sqlite, fmdb

How can I delete id's if not in array (FMDB sqlite Swift iOS)?

```
for (var i=0; i < pointId!.count; i++){
    do {
        try db.executeUpdate("delete from POINTS where ID not in ?) values (?)", values: [pointId![i]])

    } catch let error as NSError {
        print("failed: \(error.localizedDescription)")
    }
}
```

Comment: What is not working there? What results does your code give?

Comment: How large can the array be?

Comment: No happen anything or delete all rows. Do you have case ready to use for delete from where not in? It possible in sqlite?

Answer (score 1):

FMDB requires arrays to be fully expanded with question marks (it is a [long standing issue](https://github.com/ccgus/fmdb/pull/180) with FMDB):

```
try db.executeUpdate("delete from POINTS where ID not in (?, ?, ?)", values: [id1, id2, id3])
```

Of course the pain point is to build an SQL query with a variable number of question marks. *You can't avoid it now*.

You can use an utility function like [databaseQuestionMarks()](https://github.com/groue/GRDB.swift/blob/v0.46.0/GRDB/Core/Utils.swift#L17-L22) (found in the alternative SQLite wrapper [GRDB.swift](http://github.com/groue/GRDB.swift)):

```
let questionMarks = databaseQuestionMarks(count: ids.count)
let query = "delete from POINTS where ID not in (\(questionMarks))"
try db.executeUpdate(query, values: ids)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use it like this(without the use of question marks):

```
let skippedIdsStr = pointId.joined(separator: ",")
try db.executeUpdate("delete from POINTS where ID not in ("+skippedIds+")", values: [])
```